# How to install exe remotely usiing ansible, exe is downloaded on control machine

Tags: ansible, window

I am trying to install .exe(any exe) files to windows 10 machines using Ansible, but could not get it right, I have downloaded exe of the softwares to my local Ansible control machine.
I can get things done with chocolatey but I don't want the machine to go to an internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy the installer to the remote windows server using `win_copy` and then install using `win_package`.

```
---
- hosts: remote_server_name
  tasks:
  - name: Copy Installer
    win_copy:
      src: /srv/myfiles/file.exe
      dest: C:\temp\file.exe

  - name: Install 
    win_package:
      path: C:\temp\file.exe
      state: present
```